# Locking Mechanism if pod crashes while processing mongodb record

Tags: java, mongodb, kubernetes, locking, amazon-eks

We have a java/spring application which runs on EKS pods and we have records stored in MongoDB collection.

`STATUS: READY,STARTED,COMPLETED`

Application needs to pick the records which are in `READY` status and update the status to `STARTED`. Once the processing of the record is completed, the status will be updated to `COMPLETED`

Once the record is `STARTED`, it may take few hours to complete, until then other pods(other instance of the same app) should not pick this record. If some exception occurs, the app changes the status to `READY` so that other pods(or the same pod) can pick the `READY` record for processing.

**Requirement**: If the pod crashes when the record is processing(`STARTED`) but crashes before changing the status to `READY/COMPLETED`, the other pod should be able to pick this record and start processing again.

We have some solution in mind but trying to find the best solution. Request you to help me with some best approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shutdown hook from spring:

```
@Component
public class Bean1 {

    @PreDestroy
    public void destroy() {
        ## handle database change
        System.out.println(Status changed to ready);
    }
}
```

Beyond that, that kind of job could run better in a messaging architecture, using SQS for example. Instead of using the status on the database to handle and orchestrate the task, you can use an SQS, publish the message that needs to be consumed (the messages that were in ready state) and have a poll of workers consuming messages from this SQS, if something crashes or the pod of this workers needs to be reclaimed, the message goes back to SQS and can be consumed by another pod.

Comment: Agreed, but currently the data sits on DB and they don't want to use MQ. Also, the shutdown hook is not guaranteed to run all the time during JVM crashes